# Chrome - Position fixed

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm adding a tab to the right hand side of a screen, but when looking at the page in Chrome it is offset outside of the screen mostly. Yet in Firefox and other browsers, it seems perfectly set to the right.

Screenshots of both browsers :

Firefox : [image: firefox]
Chrome : [image]

Also a JS Fiddle shows this : https://jsfiddle.net/gcu6d7qL/1/

My HTML is :

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#property-alert-modal" id="property-alert-cta" class="property-alert-cta -right u-rounded-4">
    <div>
        <span class="text-uppercase f-bold c-white f-13">Sign up for <span class="f-normal">Property Alerts</span></span>
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS :

```
.property-alert-cta.-right {
    right: 0;
}
.u-rounded-4 {
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.property-alert-cta {
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    background: #5b00ff;
    -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: mixed;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 1.5em 0.8em;
}
```

Does anyone have any fixes or suggestions for this?

Thanks

Comment: Not in my Chrome it's not. - Version 76.0.3809.62 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)

Comment: add the web-kit prefix for chrome.please go through the vendor prefixes for different browsers.

Comment: @supriya This has nothing to do with vendor prefixes

Comment: ok if prefix issue not there means obviously its padding issue .added     padding: 0.8em 0em; so that it solved issue

Comment: In my version of chrome I had the same issue, also due to padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
```

Replace these lines of css code with the below.

```
-webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    -ms-writing-mode: tb-lr;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
```

Comment: correct solution IMO, I verified it works for me as well.

Comment: Works fine, Thank you! Had a suspicion it was a webkit issue.

Comment: No that just reversed the order. It will solve the padding issue but it also reverses the text. @StuBlackett

Answer (score 1):

wrap the anchor in a div:

```
        <div id="property-alert-cta" class="right">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#property-alert-modal" class="property-alert-cta -right u-rounded-4">
        <span class="text-uppercase f-bold c-white f-13">Sign up for <span class="f-normal">Property Alerts</span>
        </span>           
      </a>
    </div>
```

css:

```
  body {
    font-family: Arial;
  }
  .right {
      right: 0;
  }
  .u-rounded-4 {
      border-radius: 4px;
  }
  #property-alert-cta {
      z-index: 2;
      position: fixed;
      top: 30%;
  }

  .c-white {
    color: white;
  }

  #property-alert-cta a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #5b00ff;
    -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: mixed;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 1.5em 0.8em;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me there is an issue with chrome and safari's implementation of *writing-mode: vertical-rl;* for position fixed.
In your case one easy solution would be shift the padding to the div encapsulating your span. Because the issues is arising due the chrome not compensating for the padding properly for a vertical positioned element. Below is the code:

```css
 .property-alert-cta.-right {
    right: 0;
}
.u-rounded-4 {
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.alert-padding {
 padding: 1.5em 0.8em;

.property-alert-cta {
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    background: #5b00ff;
    -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: mixed;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 1.5em 0.8em;
}
```

```html
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#property-alert-modal" id="property-alert-cta" class="property-alert-cta -right u-rounded-4">
    <div class="alert-padding">
        <span class="text-uppercase f-bold c-white f-13">Sign up for <span class="f-normal">Property Alerts</span></span>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be because of the `padding`. When adding `right: 1.6em` (2x0.8em) this is solved for chrome.

I cannot tell you what is implemented differently in chrome here, as it does not depend on the box-sizing of the div.

**UPDATE**
In the W3 spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position), the "right" attribute is described as follows:

> Like 'top', but specifies how far a box's right margin edge is offset to the left of the right edge of the box's containing block. For relatively positioned boxes, the offset is with respect to the right edge of the box itself.

As I understand even with padding the right edge should be exactly on the right edge of the window.

Comment: the quote from the SPEC is irrelevant here because right consider the containing block and its right edge. the padding is applied to the element. Here it's related to `writing-mode`